# References for a minor variant of the Rayleigh quotient

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

I believe this variant of the Rayleigh quotient inequality must be well known but I could not find references for it online. It's proof is straightforward.

Let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ having non negative eigenvalues.
Assume the spectral decomposition of $\mathbf{A}$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_{0} &  & 0\\
 & \ddots\\
0 &  & \lambda_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)\cdot\mathbf{V}^{T},\,\mbox{s. t.}\,\,\mathbf{I}_{n}=\mathbf{U}\cdot\mathbf{V}^{T},
\end{equation}

where $0\le\lambda_{0}\le\cdots\le\lambda_{n-1}$, then for all linear combinations of columns of $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{U}$ respectively of the form 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{x}=\sum_{0\le k<n}\alpha_{k}\,\mathbf{V}\left[:,\,k\right]\;\mbox{ and }\;\mathbf{y}=\sum_{0\le k<n}\beta_{k}\,\mathbf{U}\left[:,\,k\right],
\end{equation}
such that $\left\{ \alpha_{k}\cdot\beta_{k}\right\} _{0\le k<n}\subset\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ (but not all simultaneously zero), we have
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{0}\le\frac{\mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{y}}{\mathbf{x}^{T}\cdot\mathbf{y}}\le\lambda_{n-1}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Do you have a proof for that claim? I see this for the first time (but I am not an expert on this).

Comment: Note that such a spectral decomposition may not exists e.g. when $A$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: Are $U,V$ orthonormal? If $U,V$ are orthonormal and $UV^T = I_n$ then isn't $U = V$? In that case $A$ is symmetric and $x,y$ originate from the same subspace right? In that case isn't this the basic Rayleigh inequality?